# Grey Colored box issue on web-view on text selection

Tags: android, jquery, html5-canvas, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm rendering a html page(*html page is constructed using JQuery, text with html tags, used a canvas in it*) to Activity with web-view & to default browser comes with device. When I long press on text in html page I'm getting **dark grey colored boxes** on it.This is unexpected & weird behavior of web-view.Please see attached images for my problem

[image][image]

I searched for such issue but not getting any solution for it.**Same html page is tested on Mozilla app but not getting such square boxes, also on ACER tab running HoneyComb its working fine no such weird square boxes**.How to get rid of such boxes?. I using Samsung Tab2 10.1 with android version 4.0.4. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you code for it?

But you can `validate` the page on http://validator.w3.org/

There may be problem with your `html` like any `tag` `open` but not `closed`, etc.

So once you validate it, then test it again.